# Haskell: map one element of a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm new to Haskell, and wondering what would be an idiomatic way to convert a tuple `(a,b)` to `(c,b)`. In other words, only transform the first value, leaving the second unchanged.

I can, of course, use `fst` and `snd`, but if I can `map` over lists, why not tuples?

Comment: note that tuples are functors over their second value, so `fmap :: (b -> c) -> (a, b) -> (a, c)`. Would it make more sense to change your data, or write `fmapFirst :: (a -> c) -> (a, b) -> (c, b); fmapFirst f (a, b) = (f a, b)` (or use one of the other options below)?

Comment: @AdamSmith You're telling a stormtrooper how to wield a lightsaber. I'll respond to your comment once I've figured out what it means. This is a problem I've seen with functional programmers - they forget, or don't want to, speak plain English.

Comment: `let (x, y) = ab in (f x, y)`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I thought my comment was clear from the type signatures at least. A functor is (loosely-defined, at least...) something that can be mapped over. That seems to be what you're trying to do, and tuples are already that kind of thing, just not over their first value (try it! `fmap (+2) (1, 1)`).

Comment: There is *one* type `[a]` for any type `a`. There are *many* tuple types with two elements. Tuples and lists are not the same thing, despite superficial similarities, and tuples in Haskell are very different from tuples in other languages. For instance, there are no empty tuples (although `()` is similar, which probably led to the chosen syntax) and there is no singleton tuple. Tuples are products of types, not sequences.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar and not to discourage you, but functors are a fairly elementary concept, at least in the manner that they're quick to understand and many (many many) things build on them. Perhaps the metaphor would be more like teaching a stormtrooper to wield a blaster?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any of these will do:

```
base:Data.Bifunctor.first
base:Control.Arrow.first
extra:Data.Tuple.Extra.first
(lens:Control.Lens._1 lens:Control.Lens.%~)
```

[And there are many more.](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%28a%2C+b%29+-%3E+%28c%2C+b%29&scope=set%3Astackage)

Comment: Thanks, I went with `(first $ arr length)`. My tuple is a `(List, List)`. The `Data.Tuple.Extra.first` claims to be specialized for tuples, but I don't know how to import it.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Note you don't need `arr`, as there is an `Arrow` instance for functions.